# How to connect ble device without scanning? Android 4.3

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, characteristics

I try to develop a simple android app with a ble device.
I found many source code from the Intenet. However, both of them were start from scanning a list of available ble device.
As I have MAC address of the device,UUID of service and characteristic.
How can I connect to the known device and read one specific characteristic directly??

Answer (score 2):

To connect a specific Bluetooth Device which has details like MAC address of the device, UUID of service and characteristic etc. you already know. To do this you need a BluetoothDevice object to make a call like this:

```
yourBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, bleGattCallback);
```

So for this (yourBluetoothDevice) you have to start the scan at first to get same device object to connect by comparing it's MAC address. However, you got that same device object in onLeScan callback just stop scanning and make a connection with the same device.

**Note:** Making a connection should be on UIThread(Either using Handler, runOnUIThread or mainlooperThread) otherwise it will give issue in some devices for **'Fail to register callback'**

Here yourBluetoothDevice is the device object reference with you want to make a connection.
bleGattCallback is the registered new BluetoothGattCallback() callback for connection status, discovered services, characteristics read and write etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html). Something like this:

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("<Your UUID>");
BluetoothSocket socket = yourBLEDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
Method m = yourBLEDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(yourBLEDevice, 1);
```

Comment: I try the code like this but it seems can not connect to my device Am I missing something ?????                                       myDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MACAddress);

try {btSocket=myDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
} catch (IOException e) {
          //error
        }
      
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
      
        try {
          btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
          try {
            btSocket.close();
          } catch (IOException e2) {
            //         }
        }

Comment: May be the code are so confuse. The problem I found is no response in function socket.connect();

Comment: I have edited the code. Try it out. Also, just so you know, you only have to do a scan once; after you get paired with the BLE device, your phone stores that connection data and you won't have to scan again.

Comment: Thanks Brent McFerrin. I still have something not understand. You mean that I do not need to use socket.connect() function? Then, how can I connect to the device? I have tried you code above. I found that it is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the mac address, you can try something like below:

```
final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mMacAddress);
final BluetoothGatt mGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplication(), false, gattCallback);
```

Comment: As I already know the mac address of the device so I tried as you suggested, but what happens is, the device will be connected but after 30 seconds or so it gets disconnected automatically